# Link href in email replaced with different one

Tags: c#, vb.net, email

I want to send a link via email and the href attribute is replaced with different one like this. It replace href with the email address used to send email by appending some crazy things.

```
In the code, i have like this
<a href='https://www.example.com'>Link</a>
```

When i got email, link href is converted to

```
<a href='http://test@gmail.com?ls/click?upn=FUW25JaoCKAxSHIc5WABeMtuz'>Link</a>
```

where test@gmail.com is email used to send email

Comment: Change the way you send the email. Then change the way you view the email. Then you will hopefully find out where it is being replaced.

Comment: @GSerg The href atttribute is not being changed anywhere in code. When i call Send() function on SmtpClient, it sends email and in the email, the href attribute is changed. I am not sure if mail applications like gmail or outlook are manipulating the links for security purpose. But in any case, it should redirect me to the i link i put there. This is strange.

Comment: Just to confirm, a the time of SmtpClient.Send() the href link is correct? or has it already been changed?

Comment: @Hursey The link is correct at the time of calling SmtpClient.Send().

Comment: I didn't say your code changes it. I said to try a different mail server to send it, and then separately a different way of viewing it.